# Add and Change the default value for table column with migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I currently have a migration and I simply want to add a couple more values to this migration such as to_limit and from_limit along with their default values (5&10). How should i do this?

```
class AddUserToCompany < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :companies, :user, :jsonb, default: {"to_dist"=>50, "from_dist"=>70, "trs_one"=>100,   "trs_two"=>120}
  end
end
```

I added some changes which also requires "to_limit"=>5 and "from_limit"=>10. Please suggest on how to add a new migrate file and add the changes.

Rails version - 4.2.11

This is my first time working with a rails application. So i am really confused on how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.If this changes are in progress (not already used by other) then you can rollback this migration by command

- rollback last migration

> rake db:rollback STEP=1

- In order to rollback ONLY ONE specific migration

> rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20220905201547

and after applying changes, run rake db:migrate

2. If migration was created earlier then you can create new migration to apply your changes

- generate new migration by command

> rails generate migration nameOfMigration

I hope this helps

Comment: The migration was created earlier so i will have to generate a new migration. I am a little confused regarding it. During the new migration do i add only the new details that i want to add or all of them including the existing ones. Need a small clarification regarding this. Thankyou

Comment: you can use 
change_column_default :articles, :user, from: {"to_dist"=>50, "from_dist"=>70, "trs_one"=>100, "trs_two"=>120}, to: {"to_dist"=>50, "from_dist"=>70, "trs_one"=>100, "trs_two"=>120, "new_att" => 10}
I guess you need to pass all params as we can replace full the value(but may not be change anything with current value) @Priyanshu0007